# SQL "LIKE" query doesn't find what I know it's there

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I am trying to identify which posts on a wordpress installation contains empty paragraphs, I found one manually and clicked "edit", this is what I see:

[image: img]

So then I tried a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<p> </p>%'
```

No results returned, and `"<p> </p>"` is copy pasted manually from that row I found. I've also tried REGEXP with a pattern like this :

```
#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;?)*</p>#
```

But still got no results back, what can I do to find those empty paragraphs?

Comment: Are you sure that the tag data isn't encoded in the actually table?

Comment: Don't assume a tag has no content because it only contains whitespace.  `<p><span></span><b></b></p>` has no content but in practical terms, is an empty paragraph.

Comment: If your goal is to remove empty `p` tags, the best solution would be to parse every row with a tree based HTML parser.  Remove the empty nodes from the document tree and put it back in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you searching on `post_title` instead of `post_content`?

```
SELECT ID
  FROM `wp_posts`
 WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<p> </p>%'
```

Should work. If you want to use `REGEXP` and allow for paragraphs with `&nbsp;` in them:

```
SELECT ID
  FROM `wp_posts`
 WHERE `post_content` REGEXP '<p>[[:blank:]]*(&nbps;)?[[:blank:]]*</p>'
```

Comment: Sorry I fixed the error on the query I posted, I was searching post_content but I made a mistake when posting the question.

Comment: Yes, but i get "#1139 - Got error 'invalid character class' from regexp", still trying to figure out why.

Comment: @user979390 Sorry, try again. I missed a couple of colons.

Comment: Now it found 4 results, but I know there are MUCH more, for example the one on the screenshot was not found with that query, this is so weird.

Comment: @user979390 Can you run this query: `SELECT HEX(post_content) FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=627` and post the results into something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/) (and give me the link, of course)?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I ended up using REGEXP '<p>.{1,2}</p>'. it found all the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%<p> </p>%'
```

To this:

```
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<p> </p>%'
```

And try again.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the error on the query I posted, I was searching post_content but I made a mistake when posting the question. I have no results back from the query even when using post_content

Answer (score 0):

well.. like should work..

but an alternate might be to use instr

something like `WHERE instr( post_content, '<p> </p>' ) > 0`